# Вывод данных из MySQL в телеграмм бота pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, mysql, telebot

Необходимо чтобы бот отправлял данные из БД по указанному условию

```
        if message.text == 'Девушку':
        mycursor.execute("SELECT name, city, age, about FROM users WHERE sex = 'Девушка' ")
        finds = mycursor.fetchall()
        print(finds)

        random_find = random.choice(finds)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, random_find)
```

[image: Вывод информации рандного столбца из строки]

Если пробую так, то Бот в телеграмме выводит **одно** рандомное имя из данного кортежа 
 Есть тестовые анкеты, получается одна строка в БД - анкета юзера имя/город/возраст/о себе
Как написать код, чтобы бот выводил **рандомно** одну из строк БД в формате(например из моих данных):
*Света, Казань, 20

Низкая*

 Получается в консоль выводится список со вложенным кортежом.
Я недавно в программировании, нужна помощь)

Comment: Оффтоп, `sex = 'Девушка'`, а какие у вас еще есть варианты значений `sex`? :)

Comment: @gil9red Еще имеется 'Парень'
Пытаюсь написать бота знакомств. Решил создать собственный проект, так как лучшее изучение - это практика и разбираться по ходу дела) Однако вопросов очень много( Если у Вас есть возможность помочь мне, в плане консультации по возникающим вопросам, то было бы замечательно...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно просто извлечь значения и составить строку нужного формата:

```
name, city, age, about = random.choice(finds)
text = f'{name}, {city}, {age}\n{about}'

bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text)
```